# Prometheus http api not returning result same as webUI

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want get the same result as webui while using prometheus http api, but i am struggling in that.

When i use promql on prometheus webUI i get series of records like below :

[image]

However when i use the http api of same cluster, i just get single result for same promql:

```
 GET http://ip_address:9091/api/v1/query?query='max by (server) (max_over_time( pem_cpu_usage{service="postgres" }[1h]))'
```

give me single response :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "string",
        "result": [
            1686577506.211,
            "max by (server) (max_over_time( pem_cpu_usage{service=\"postgres\" }[1h]))"
        ]
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1 :**
I am further trying to understand the issue:

**SUCCESS**: Below http api gives me desired values in response same as webui :

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:9091/api/v1/query?query=up
```

**FAILED**: However as soon as i apply some label as filter it does not give any result. but the webui gives me filtered result.

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:9091/api/v1/query?query=up{instance="valid_instance_name"}
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "vector",
        "result": []
    }
}

http://IP_ADDRESS:9091/api/v1/query?query='up{instance="valid_instance_name"}'

{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "string",
        "result": [
            1686611284.546,
            "up{instance=\"valid_instance_name\"}"
        ]
    }
}

http://IP_ADDRESS:9091/api/v1/query?query='up%7Binstance%3D"valid_instance_name"%7D'


{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "string",
        "result": [
            1686610890.633,
            "up{instance=\"valid_instance_name\"}"
        ]
    }
}

http://IP_ADDRESS:9091/api/v1/query?query=up%7Binstance%3D"valid_instance_name"%7D
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "vector",
        "result": []
    }
}
```

**UPADATE-2** Found the issue :
The webUI was in fact hitting the different host, As i don't have control on infra so was given wrong host name for API, but during debugging we identified why i was not getting any data. Sorry for creating this ticket.. ideally it should be deleted.

Comment: I don't know what is your problem. For this [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=max%20by%20(mode)%20(max_over_time(%20node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1h%5D))&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h) this curl works as intended: `curl  'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query?query=max+by+%28mode%29+%28max_over_time%28+node_cpu_seconds_total%5B1h%5D%29%29'`

Comment: weird part is that no matter what query i excute the result value is always same which is current epoch timestamp .. for example 1686577506.211.

Comment: Hah, i missed that. You have single quotes around your query. Prometheus interprets this as query for the string: consider [this demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=%27up%27&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h). You need to remove that quote (and most likely add url encoding), and everything should work.

Comment: I must be doing some silly mistake but check my updated comment.. i have tried with removing quote and added encoding as well.. but no luck if my query has any label as fitler.

Comment: Open web developer tool (`F12`) in your browser on Prometheus page, press Execute on page near thee query and see network tab of developer tool. You can copy curl command from there (at least in firefox). Investigate from there.

Comment: Thank you !!..  Found the issue .. the webUI was in fact hitting the different host ... As i don't have control on infra so was given wrong host name for API... but during debugging we identified why i was not getting any data.